# Should I save weights separately when I save model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I made NN in Keras that gives me validation accuracy of 88%, but when I load that model, and make prediction with it, I get only 52% of accuracy, so I wondering what am I doing wrong.
I have saved my model and my scaler, and loaded them afterwards.

```
model.save("my model.h5")

scaler_filename = "keras nn scaler.save"
joblib.dump(scaler, scaler_filename)
```

And then im loading the model like this:

```
my_model = load_model("my model.h5")
```

And Im making prediction like this:

```
scaler = joblib.load("keras nn scaler.save") 
validation_features = scaler.transform(validation_features)

prediction = my_model.predict(validation_features , batch_size=64)
```

Accuracy like this:

```
res = []
for p in prediction:
    res.append(p[0].round(0))


# Accuracy with sklearn - much lower 
acc_score = accuracy_score(validation_results, res)
print("Sklearn acc", round(acc_score,2))  # 52%
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 52% is the test accuracy?

Comment: When I was making a model, I got around 89-90 % acc of my test data, and 87-88% on my validation data. And when I loaded the model, and made a prediction, I got 52%

Comment: Can you share the code for initialising the weights?

Comment: You mean my whole network, with layers?

Comment: What's your Keras version?

Comment: I have 2.1.6-tf

Comment: I added kears like : from tensorflow.python import keras

Comment: Answer not helpful?